# Fill Remaining Column Space With Image

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Hello I am working on a mockup with Bootstrap 4. I am wondering how I can fill in the remaining space of this red bordered column without distorting the image?

I am currently using img-fluid to keep it responsive, but to my understanding this only fills the full width of it's container therefore leaving whitespace for the height.

[image: Example]

```
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="container">
            <h3>COMMAND THE ROAD</h3>
            <p>The power and driving dynamics of the all-new 2020 Explorer come wrapped in an eye-catching design that
              boasts
              authentic comfort and style. And because it was built for the active lifestyle, you can also expect an
              interior
              space that accommodates the kids, the dog, the sports equipment, camping gear and just about anything else
              you
              may need on the road to adventure.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="img/20_FRD_EPR_400079_1_.jpg" class="img-fluid overflow-hidden">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of looking around and trial and error, it was solved with a simple

```
img {
height:100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [object-fit: cover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) to resize the image to fill the whole space while keeping the ratio intact. Keep in mind that it will cut some portion of the image. If you're not satisfied with the position of the image you can tweak it more with [object-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position)

```css
.cover {
  object-fit: cover;
}

.fill {
  object-fit: fill;
}

.contain {
  object-fit: contain;
}

img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 10px solid red;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1070/5472/3648.jpg" class="cover">
<img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1070/5472/3648.jpg" class="fill">
<img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1070/5472/3648.jpg" class="contain">
```

Comment: How can I do this with columns whilst keeping it responsive?

Comment: It all depends what you want to achieve. If you want to make the image to cover the whole space of the right column, I'd remove `img-fluid` class and apply `width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;`. It can however be higher than the left column as it is determined by the original height of the image (same as with `img-fluid`). If you want it to be no higher than the left column, remove `<img>` and use the image as a background for right column and add `min-height` so it will have some height in mobile view. There are many ways and options but without full specs I can only guess.

Comment: The idea is to have it look similar to the using it as a background image in a div, but retain it's img properties and maintaining the size of the column to it's left.